# Calling parameterized constructor in same class c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have class like this.

```
public abstract class Service<T> : IService<T> where T : class
{

        private readonly IRepository<T> _repository;
        private readonly IFooService _fooService;
        protected Service(IRepository<T> repository)
            : this(repository,??)
        {
        }

        private Service(
            IRepository<T> repository,
            IFooService fooService)
        {
            _repository = repository;
            _fooService= fooService;
        }
}
```

Now, How can I pass parameter for calling private constructor like **this(repository,??)**. I don't want this IFooService calling from public. My this IFooService is fixed.

Comment: new FooService()? not sure what the problem is

Comment: a) Pass `null` and add a special case in the other constructor to handle that. b) Write two complete constructors and don't call one from the other.

Comment: Problem is FooService class has also parameterized constructor. I am using also Unity DI container.@maximdumont

Comment: @RIKhan If this service is being resolved through a DI container, then I would argue that it is not a fixed service. Is there a particular reason this has to be private?